# Program aborts - Prime factor of numbers read from a file

Tags: c++, memory, backtracking

This code decomposes a number into its prime factors.

The numbers are taken from a file. The first number from the file represents the number of elements in it, the numbers are from the interval [1, 10^18].

The problem with the code is that after reading and decomposing some numbers it stops. It is intended to decompose somewhere between 100 and 1000 numbers from which at least half are bigger than 10^9.

I suspect that the stack overflows, but I am not 100% sure. I would like to hear some suggestions in order to fix this memory allocation problem.
Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void print_recurenta(int a,int i)
{
    if((a==1)||(i>a))
        return;
    if(a%i==0)
    {
        printf("%d  ",i);
        a=a/i;
        print_recurenta(a,i);
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
        print_recurenta(a,i);
    }
}

void factor_printf(int nr)
{
    printf("\n%ld  ",nr);
    int i=2;
    print_recurenta(nr,i);

}


int main()
{
    int numere;
    int  nr=0;
    FILE* f=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(f==0)
        return -1;
    fscanf(f,"%d",&numere);
    while(fscanf(f,"%d",&nr)!=EOF)
    {
        fscanf(f,"%d",&nr);
        factor_printf(nr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is your `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Actually I don't see how it could work at all with this line: `fscanf(f,"d",&nr);`..

Comment: You are right about the stack overflow too. If one of the factors is in the billion range, you could need tens of gigabytes of stackspace for the recursive calls. You could try looping instead.

Comment: Start by finding a data type big enough to hold the input. Every 3 decimal digits takes 10 bits. So 18 digits takes 60 bits. So your (likely 32-bit int is too short).

Comment: `scanf` is one of the most error prone kludges in C.  I won't try to guess what errors beyond the obvious you might be making with `scanf`.  I'm not even a fan of simplistic parsing with `stream >>`  (vs. read a line into a `std::string` and parse it more carefully) but `stream >>` is at least easier to get right than `fscanf`.

Comment: You have tagged this as C++, but I see no classes referenced, and the functions printf, fscanf (and using FILE*) are defined in <cstdio>  These files are designed for backward compatibility to the other language.  C++ uses streams, cout, cin, etc.  There is nothing wrong with using C, so why the confusion?

Comment: the line "printf("\n%ld  ",nr);" generates "warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]"

Comment: The basic correction to the excess recursion is simply use a loop instead of recursion.  Sometimes it takes some thought to convert a simple recursive operation into a loop.  But here you seem to have done the reverse and converted a simple loop into recursion for no reason.

Comment: My guess is - this is an exercise in recursion (as it doesn't look like production code for factorization), so looping is out of the question. You can reduce the depth of the recursion by (1) testing only odd factors above 2; (2) terminating recursion when `i*i > a`

Comment: Failing to stop at sqrt `a` when `a` happens to be prime means that after fixing all other bugs, if you are given one very large prime as input, your program will effectively hang.  If you did stop at sqrt `a` 1000 big primes would be very slow (after all bugs fixed).  Doing a prime sieve first and storing that would be faster.

Comment: @VladFeinstein just how stupid do you thing the instructor was for this to be assigned as an exercise in recursion?  Your suggestion still falls short of making recursion work.

Comment: the program works; it does what it is supposed to do but it crashes with "main.exe has stopped working" after its execution;

Comment: @JSF - Re: `just how stupid do you thing the instructor was` - is that a rhetorical question? :) That was just the first step; my next suggestion would be to replace the `i++;` line with a call to GetNextPrime(i); then to cache those primes, as the program is supposed to run on multiple inputs. Question for you: *WHY* do you think the recursion is used here?

Comment: @VladFeinstein not necessarily rhetorical: someone might have a lower opinion of typical computer science instructors than I have (not likely but possible).  So you could actually think an instructor was that stupid.  My better guess is that the previous assignment focused on recursion, so the OP forgot that he has a choice.  In this assignment recursion is just **WRONG** (rearrange the deck chairs all you like:  that ship still sinks).

Comment: because it has better execution time then loops....with numbers with maximum 8 integers the program works fine 0.01-0.09 s

Comment: @Bernat whatever loop you wrote to discover recursion was faster, was  wrong.  Recursion is slower, even when it doesn't exceed the stack.  A loop is not limited to changing only one variable.  In one loop `a` can go down and `i` can go up.  Recursion, changing both things that ought to change, is faster than looping, changing only one of them.  But that is not an advantage to recursion, just an advantage to avoiding a specific mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This problem *CAN* be solved recursively if we look for the next factor in a loop:

```
void print_recurenta(__int64 a, __int64 i)
{
    if (a == 1)
        return;

    if (i*i > a)
    {
        printf("%llu  ", a);
        return;
    }

    if (a%i == 0)
    {
        printf("%llu  ", i);
        a = a / i;
    }
    else
    {
        for (++i; i*i < a && (a%i != 0); ++i)
            ;
    }
    print_recurenta(a, i);
}
```